# Can someone explain the 'mod' operator in VB.net in the simplest way possible?

Tags: vb.net, operators

I have this code I need to explain and the Mod operator has confused me, MSDN has a page on it and I cannot understand it clearly. I have included a section of code below if you could refer to it in your answer, thanks.

```
number1 = (input1/ 10) - 0.5
number2 = input2 Mod 10

Result = number1 + number2
```

Comment: [Divides two numbers and returns only the remainder.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se0w9esz.aspx)

Comment: But the example on MSDN says Debug.WriteLine(10 Mod 5)
' Output: 0

Comment: because 10 divided by 5 is 2 *with no remainder*.  `11 Mod 5` would be 1

Comment: mod is always funny learning because by the time we get to it, we've forgotten elementary school division.

Comment: @VoronoiPotato I like mod because it almost seems too simple, and because it comes in handy sometimes -- but definitely because we forget elementary school division, yeah. :)

Answer (score 12):

`Mod` in VB.NET is the Modulo operation. It returns the remainder when one number is divided by another.

For example, if you divided 4 by 2, your mod result would be 0 (no remainder). If you divided 5 by 2, your mod result would be 1.

[Explanation of the Modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)

Comment: Thank you for your response